# bash find if a variable contains a symbol and escape it

Tags: bash, sed

I have written a bash script for Mac OS X that gathers a lot of computer information and writes it to a MySQL database. Everything works fine except one thing. One of the pieces of information I gather is the Computer Name. Probably around 90% of the computers have an apostrophe in their names. The problem is that when I try to write the variable to MySQL it errors out due to the apostrophe.

Is there a way to find if a variable contains an apostrophe and if it does rewrite the variable with the escape character? I am sure I need to use sed but I am still pretty new to this.

For example if I have the following variable:

```
COMPUTER_NAME="Fred Flintstone's MacBook Air"
```

How can I change the variable to:

```
COMPUTER_NAME="Fred Flintstone\'s MacBook Air"
```

I can pass this off to perl of I **need** to but I would rather keep it in BASH.

I also don't want to rename the computers because there are over 300 of them.

Comment: You can `sed "s/'/\\\'/g"`

Answer (score 1):

This will escape apostrophes that are not already escaped:

```
${COMPUTER_NAME/[^\\]\'/\\\'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this to escape what you want :

```
string="Hello, c'est bientôt l'été ?"
printf '%q\n' "$string"
```

### Output

```
$'Hello, c\'est bient\303\264t l\'\303\251t\303\251 ?'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will use bash quoting/escaping conventions which probably won't match MySQL's conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parameter expansion with substitution:

```
COMPUTER_NAME="${COMPUTER_NAME//\'/\'}"
```